# Is it a good practice to set all the fields to null?

Tags: java

Is it a good practice to have all the fields equal to null and just create them when they are required ?

```
public class Products {

   private Map listofProducts = null;
   private Owner owner = null;
   private List<listOfProductsResults> listofProductsResults = null;
   private String fileName = null;
   private long id = 0L;


   public Products(){
   }
```

In this way whenever a method needs each of them I do the following

```
  if(listOfProducts == null){
      this.listOfProducts = new HashMap();
  }
```

Comment: No, it makes no difference. They are initialized to `null` by default anyway.

Comment: No, don't do that. It is utterly annoying to look at

Comment: The only time you would (or should really) do this, if with local variables.

Comment: Don't do it. Save typing, disk space and time. It's "code noise".

Comment: how about the local variables ? should I set them to null at the end of the method?

Answer (score 1):

```
private Map listofProducts = null;
```

and

```
private Map listOfProducts;
```

Are equal statements, so no. It is pointless and I really don't like the look of the code with this.

Comment: How will setting myInt = null make a difference there?

Comment: I've just removed the example. I wrote it very late!

Answer (score 0):

Java auto initializes objects to null, but sometimes setting it to null explicitly can be a form of documentation if nothing else. For example, normally one would expect a constructor to initialize instance attributes. The one property explicitly initialized to null could say "this is not initialized in the constructor" or "this uses lazy initialization, beware". That might signify to always proxy through a getter or expect access to be protected with a null check. But it would be up to you to establish such a pattern.

Comment: I see, does that mean that I should not initialize them but should check whether object is null or not?

Comment: @AlexCartio1 Of course you should check for null rather than get `NullPointerExceptions,` but it isn't implied by anything stated in this answer.

Comment: how about local variables? should I set them to null at the end of the method ?

Comment: You should check for null if something is designed or documented to possibly be null. If you are the one designing the class and its members then you would know if it could be null or not.

Comment: Setting any variable to null removes a reference to an object. If it was the only reference it will become garbage collected. But since local variables are removed at the end of the function scope, then you do not need to do this.